# Normalize quadratic form (parabolic pillar)

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I cannot normalize a real quadratic form $F(x,y,z)$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
F(x,y,z) &=& ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + 2fyz + 2gzx + 2hxy + 2lx + 2my + 2nz + d.
\end{eqnarray}
Here, the principal matrix $A$, and matrix of the quadratic form $\tilde{A}$ are
as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
A &=& \begin{pmatrix}
 a & h & g \\
 h & b & f \\
 g & f & c \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
\tilde{A} &=& \begin{pmatrix}
 a & h & g & l \\
 h & b & f & m\\
 g & f & c & n\\
 l & m & n & d \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

If rank($A$) = 1 and rank($\tilde{A}$) =  3, it should be parabolic pillar, and 
the quadratic form becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
F(x', y', z') = \lambda x'^2 + r z' 
\end{eqnarray}
but I can't show why the coefficient of $y'$ becomes zero.

--

My understanding is below.
Because rank($A$) is 1, there is a non-zero eigen value $\lambda$ and
there is a regular matrix $P$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
A' = {}^t P A P = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{eqnarray}
Then by using variable conversion ($x',y',z'$) and constants ($p, q, r$) like
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\ y' \\ z' \\
\end{pmatrix}
= P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z \\
\end{pmatrix}, \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
p \\
q \\
r \\
\end{pmatrix}
= {}^t P \begin{pmatrix}
l \\ m \\ n\\
\end{pmatrix}, 
\end{eqnarray}
the quadratic form becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
F(x',y',z') = \lambda x'^2 + 2 p x' + 2 q y' + 2 r z' + d
\end{eqnarray}
and the matrix of this quadratic form is
\begin{eqnarray}
\tilde{A'} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & 0 & p \\
0       & 0 & 0 & q \\
0       & 0 & 0 & r \\
p       & q & r & d \\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{eqnarray}
If  ${\rm rank}(\tilde{A}) = 3$, ${\rm rank}(\tilde{A'})$ is also 3,
therefore either of the determinant of 3x3 minor matrix
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & p \\
0 & 0 & r \\
p & r & d
\end{vmatrix}, \quad
\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & p \\
0 & 0 & q \\
p & q & d
\end{vmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
is not zero. Hence, $r$ or $q$ is not zero at least. However, I cant show either of $r, q$ is zero.

Comment: Do you mean a parabolic _cylinder_?

Comment: Yes I do. F(x,y,z)=0 is a parabolic cylinder.